# Converting long to binary in Java gives 31 bits?

Tags: java

I understand that Unix time should be a 32 bit (4 byte) value. To calculate current UNIX time, I'm using the following:

```
long time = (System.currentTimeMillis())/1000;
```

This works fine - I get the same value as when I do this on the Unix command shell: 
"date +%s".

I want to represent this in binary, though. So I tried this:

```
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(time));
```

However, I only get 31 bits, not 32 as I would have expected. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Tim

Comment: signed 32bit int = 31 bits of actual number available, and 1 bit for the sign?

Comment: This method skips leading zeros.

Comment: Long.toBinaryString(0) gives you a simple "0". Thats just how toBinaryString works.

Comment: @MarcB: In Java, `long` is a signed *64-bit* integer.

Comment: Oracle has fallen on hard times and has had to implement an austerity program, so you don't get any extra bits.

Comment: Its because you are printing a positive no. If you do System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(-time)); it will print 64 bits i.e the signed long value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leading zeros aren't being displayed.  Try this:

```
long l = -1;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(l));
```

Or:

```
long l = Long.MIN_VALUE;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(l));
```

Or:

```
long l = -2112;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(l));
```

You should see all 64 bits. (long in Java is 64 bits, not 32)

I hope that helps.

EDIT:

If you just want a String representation of 32 bits with all the leading zeros, you could do any of a number of things.  One is:

```
int i = 42;
String result = String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println(result);
```

Another is:

```
int i = 42;
String result = String.format("%032d", Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(i)));
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that long is a 64 bit value. I really want to store this value as 32 bits so I tried this instead:

int time = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis())/1000);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(time));

I'm still getting 31 bits. To your point about the leading zeroes missing, how would I get to see them using my "time" variable? Your examples are negative numbers.

Comment: See examples I added above.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The second example throws a NumberFormatException but the first one works great.

Comment: I am surprised that the example throws a NumberFormatException for you.  I just now copied and pasted each of those examples directly out of the browser here into an editor and ran them and they all worked.  Anyway, I am glad you have a solution that works for you.