# How can I convert a long to its binary 32 bit representation?

Tags: java, string, casting, binary, long-integer

I am doing the following programming exercise: [int32 to IPv4](https://www.codewars.com/kata/52e88b39ffb6ac53a400022e). The statement is:

> Take the following IPv4 address: 128.32.10.1
>
> This address has 4 octets where each octet is a single byte (or 8
>   bits).
>
> ```
> 1st octet 128 has the binary representation: 10000000
> 2nd octet 32 has the binary representation: 00100000
> 3rd octet 10 has the binary representation: 00001010
> 4th octet 1 has the binary representation: 00000001
> ```
>
> So 128.32.10.1 == 10000000.00100000.00001010.00000001
>
> Because the above IP address has 32 bits, we can represent it as the
>   unsigned 32 bit number: 2149583361
>
> Complete the function that takes an unsigned 32 bit number and returns
>   a string representation of its IPv4 address. Examples
>
> 2149583361 ==> "128.32.10.1" 32         ==> "0.0.0.32" 0          ==>
>   "0.0.0.0"

First, I tried the following code:

```
public class Kata {
    public static String longToIP(long ip) {
        System.out.println("ip: "+ip);
    String binary = Long.toBinaryString(ip);
    System.out.println("binary: "+binary);
    return String.format("%s.%s.%s.%s",Long.parseLong(binary.substring(0,8),2),Long.parseLong(binary.substring(8,16),2),
            Long.parseLong(binary.substring(16,24),2),Long.parseLong(binary.substring(24),2));
    }
}
```

And being the tests:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Random;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class KataTest {
    @Test
    public void sampleTest() {
        assertEquals("128.114.17.104", Kata.longToIP(2154959208L));
        assertEquals("0.0.0.0", Kata.longToIP(0));
        assertEquals("128.32.10.1", Kata.longToIP(2149583361L));
    }
}
```

When input is zero, my code throws an exception: `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 8, length 1
at Kata.longToIP(Kata.java:6)`

Because of at line 4, where I convert from long to string, binary has not padding zeros:

```
ip: 0
binary: 0
```

How could I cast the long ip value to a binary string with always 32 digits (adding padding 0)?

I tried the following approach:

```
public class Kata {
    public static String longToIP(long ip) {
        System.out.println("ip: "+ip);
    String binary = String.format("%032d",Long.parseLong(Long.toBinaryString(ip)));
    System.out.println("binary: "+binary);
    return String.format("%s.%s.%s.%s",Long.parseLong(binary.substring(0,8),2),Long.parseLong(binary.substring(8,16),2),
            Long.parseLong(binary.substring(16,24),2),Long.parseLong(binary.substring(24),2));
    }
}
```

And it throws `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10000000011100100001000101101000" at Kata.longToIP(Kata.java:4)`

Then I changed it to:

```
public class Kata {
    public static String longToIP(long ip) {
        System.out.println("ip: "+ip);
    String binary = String.format("%032d",Long.parseLong(Long.toBinaryString(ip),2));
    System.out.println("binary: "+binary);
    return String.format("%s.%s.%s.%s",Long.parseLong(binary.substring(0,8),2),Long.parseLong(binary.substring(8,16),2),
            Long.parseLong(binary.substring(16,24),2),Long.parseLong(binary.substring(24),2));
    }
}
```

And this also throws an exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "00000021"
at Kata.longToIP(Kata.java:7)
```

I have read:

- [Converting long to binary in Java gives 31 bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456718/converting-long-to-binary-in-java-gives-31-bits)
- [Java - parse binary to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106229/java-parse-binary-to-long)

Comment: int32 is an `int` not a `long`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Kata {
    public static String longToIP(long ip) {
        //1. translate the ip to binary representation
        String str = "";
        if (ip == 0) {
            str = ip + "";
        } else {
            while (ip != 0) {
                str = ip % 2 + str;
                ip = ip / 2;
            }
        }

        //2. if the binary string is shorter than 32 bit, then add "0" in front
        while (str.length() != 32) {
            str = "0" + str;
        }

        String result = "";

        //3. truncate the str to four items
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            String partStr = str.substring(i * 8, 8 * (i + 1));

            //4. translate every item to decimal number
            int bi = Integer.parseInt(partStr, 2);
            if (i == 3) {
                result += bi + "";
            } else {
                result += bi + ".";
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We could add padding zeros:

```
public class Kata {
    public static String longToIP(long ip) {
        System.out.println("ip: "+ip);
    String binary = Long.toBinaryString(ip);
    if(binary.length()<32) binary = "0".repeat(32-binary.length()) + binary;
    System.out.println("binary: "+binary);
    return String.format("%s.%s.%s.%s",Long.parseLong(binary.substring(0,8),2),Long.parseLong(binary.substring(8,16),2),
            Long.parseLong(binary.substring(16,24),2),Long.parseLong(binary.substring(24),2));
    }
}
```

Or, we could do it in the same sentence where we convert from long to binary string, using format (based on [Jeff Scott Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3533584/jeff-scott-brown) answer to this topic [Converting long to binary in Java gives 31 bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456718/converting-long-to-binary-in-java-gives-31-bits):

```
public class Kata {
    public static String longToIP(long ip) {
        System.out.println("ip: "+ip);
    String binary = String.format("%32s",Long.toBinaryString(ip)).replace(' ','0'); 
    System.out.println("binary: "+binary);
    return String.format("%s.%s.%s.%s",Long.parseLong(binary.substring(0,8),2),Long.parseLong(binary.substring(8,16),2),
            Long.parseLong(binary.substring(16,24),2),Long.parseLong(binary.substring(24),2));
    }
}
```

In addition we could use net java libraries ([Angelwrith](https://www.codewars.com/kata/reviews/599d14df794ba5ca17000002/groups/5dde8aba7c31700001327d8c) solution):

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Kata {
  public static String longToIP(long ip) {
    try {
         return InetAddress.getByName(String.valueOf(ip)).getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert an int value to the standard dotted quad format, this will work. It is a simple matter of shifting the values from the left by decreasing values of 8 and appending the appropriate strings.

```
    public static String toIP(int x) {
        String ip = Integer.toString((int) (x >> 24 & 0xFF)) + ".";
        ip += Integer.toString((int) ((x >> 16) & 0xFF)) + ".";
        ip += Integer.toString((int) ((x >> 8) & 0xFF)) + ".";
        ip += Integer.toString((int) (x & 0xFF));
        return ip;
    }
```

To convert an int to a padded binary value of length 32, try the following.  It ensures that the passed int is converted to a 33 bit value so the standard `Long.toBinaryString` method will return a 33 character value.  The first character is tossed since it has served its purpose.

```
    public static String toPaddedBinary(int v) {
        long x = (v|(1L<<32))&0x1FFFFFFFFL;
        return Long.toBinaryString(x).substring(1);
    }
```

The following code shows the output.

```
        int [] data = {32, 1233, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, 192<<24|156<<16|5};
        for (int d : data) {
            System.out.println(toIP(d));
            System.out.println(toPaddedBinary(d));
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Prints

```
0.0.0.32
00000000000000000000000000100000

0.0.4.209
00000000000000000000010011010001

127.255.255.255
01111111111111111111111111111111

128.0.0.0
10000000000000000000000000000000

192.156.0.5
11000000100111000000000000000101
```